# Access application controller variable before class name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, subdomain

I want to access `application_controller` variable before class name of another controller

```
class TodosController < eval("#{subdomain_name.humanize}Controller")
```

I want to customize my `ToDoController` to inherit different controllers for different subdomains.

Comment: Instead of `eval`, you should probably use `"#{something}Controller".constantize`, but in any case, this sounds like a very bad idea. Maybe if you described what you wanted to achieve in more detail, someone could point you to a better solution.

Comment: You can't dynamically change ancestors that way, however you can include new modules

Comment: @oseiskar I am working with subdomain routing and I want to use all filters and restrictions for a resource named Todo by inhereting those controllers here. If I can access any variable of my application controller in this area class TodosController < eval("#{subdomain_name.humanize}Controller") that will reduce my work by 50%

Comment: I know other alternatives to achieve this task but I wanted to know that can I inherit controllers dynamically it will reduce a huge effort of mine.

Answer (score -1):

Just make the implementations of the inherited methods depend on the subdomain.

One way of avoiding such methods becoming and if-else-case-jungle is to use separate objects to model the subdomain-specific "policies". Here is one possible solution for implementing a subdomain-specific before filter

```
class TodosController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :require_foobar_is_allowed

  # ...
end
```

Define the filter in application controller (or a concern included to `TodosController`)

```
class ApplicationController

    # ...

protected

    def require_foobar_is_allowed
        unless subdomain_policy.foobar_allowed_for?(current_user)
            render nothing: true, status: 403
        end
    end

    def subdomain_policy
        "#{subdomain_name}Policy".constantize.new
    end
end
```

And then define the implementation in domain-specific policy objects (plain-old Ruby objects), can be placed to e.g., `app/models/`

```
class FoobarSubdomainPolicy
    def foobar_allowed_for?(user)
        # in the foobar subdomain, foobar is allowed for everyone
        true
    end
end

class BazSubdomainPolicy
    def foobar_allowed_for?(user)
        # in the baz subdomain, foobar is only allowed for admins
        user.admin?
    end
end
```

Depending on what the "inherited" functionality actually looks like, there might also exist ready-made solutions in gems such as Devise.

Comment: I do have knowledge about these alternatives. Just want confirm the possibility of my senario.

Comment: As already stated by charlysisto, your solution does not work if the subdomain can change from one request to another, because the ancestor is only evaluated at class load time, i.e., on first request.